# Use System.Net namespace in wine-mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono, wine

I'm trying to write a .Net executable for Windows, working on OS X. I thought the best way to do that and have it most likely work when run on an actual Windows machine (short of installing Windows in a VM on my Mac) would be to compile it and test it in mono under wine.

Since my program needs to make HTTP Get requests, I'm trying to use the System.Net namespace `using System.Net`, but when I try to compile the C# code, I get "error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Net' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?".

I've done Google searching and tried adding various `/reference:…` options to my `mcs` command, but nothing seems to work. I've tried referencing `System.Net`, `System.Net.dll`, `System.dll` (which should be automatic anyway) `System` and a few others, but in all cases, I get "error CS0006: Metadata file `' could not be found".

Any ideas?

Comment: Mono runs natively on OS X.  What benefit does wine bring?

Comment: @piedar Possibly none, I suppose. I'm new to Mono and C# though, and since I'm targeting Windows, I want to ensure that the code depends only on things available in a Windows environment and not on anything that might only work in a POSIX-like environment.

Comment: If you can figure out where those DLLs are, try using the -lib option: `mcs -lib:/usr/lib/mono/4.5`

Comment: OK. I just tried `wine mcs /lib:'c:\windows\mono\mono-2.0\lib\mono\4.5' …` and got the same error that I got without any command line options, which is "error CS0234: The type or namespace name \`Net' does not exist in the namespace \`System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

Comment: @piedar has already told you that you don't need `wine`